# "Does Gilles have his own Meta site?" or "A bug in the Android app"

Tags: bug, android-app

While looking through a few things on the Android app, I looked at Gilles' profile page. When I was done there, I clicked on the nifty MSE symbol in the left bar to navigate to MSE, and found a Stack Exchange site dedicated to Gilles:

[image: screenshot of the Android app, displaying the name "Gilles" next to "Meta Stack Exchange" in the top bar, where it presumably does not belong]

Android 4.2.2, app version 1.0.71

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'd sign up.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro] How did you navigate exactly? Can you reproduce it?

Comment: @Gilles I'm not on my tablet at the moment, but I clicked on a Unix & Linux comment of yours to get to your profile, and then clicked on the MSE symbol to get to MSE. If memory serves, the U&L question was a HNQ from my feed.

Comment: Lets tag this [tag:status-bydesign] and move on...

Comment: @rene [tag:status-by-gilles] would fit better.

Comment: Perhaps this might not be helpful, but.. no repro on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.85 (beta). I'm guessing this is a tablet-only issue, due to "always-shown" navigation drawer on the left. The app header/title might be conflicting, showing user profile & current site. Is this still happening, or are there better steps to repro this?